# Almost isometric subspaces of $\ell_p$

Tags: banach-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

1) Given $p\in (1,\infty)$.

2) Let us **fix** two, **non-isometric** subspaces $X,Y\subseteq \ell_p$ isomorphic to $\ell_p$.

3) **Are there** an $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$ and **an isomorphism** $S\colon X\to Y$ such that

$$(1-\varepsilon)\|x\|\leqslant \|Sx\|\leqslant (1+\varepsilon)\|x\|$$

holds for each $x\in X$?

Comment: Take $X = Y = l^p$? That works with $\epsilon = 0$. Or are you trying to find examples that fail for small $\epsilon$?  I don't understand the question.

Comment: I ask about an arbitrary pair $(X,Y)$.

Comment: Could you please make the quantifiers in your question more precise? Are you asking if subspaces isomorphic to $\ell_1$ must necessarily be close in Banach-Mazur distance? (In which case, I think the answer is no.) Or are you asking if there exists a constant $C>1$ such that any subspace which has BM-distance $\leq C$ from $\ell_p$ is in fact isometric to $\ell_p$?

Comment: Typo in comment: it should have read: "are you asking if subspaces isomorphic to $\ell_p$ must ..."

Comment: That doesn't really help me understand what you're asking. (Nor does your edit that $X$ and $Y$ can't be isometric.)

Comment: I share some of Nik Weaver's misgivings/confusion. Do you want $S$ to be a bijection from $X$ to $Y$?

Comment: The subject says "almost isometric", so maybe part (3) should be "for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $S$" ...

Comment: Voting to close. Even in its latest form, after several revisions, it is not clear what question the OP *actually* has in mind

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is an isomorphism  $T:X\to Y$ so that 
there exists constants $a < A$ such that 
$$ a \Vert x\Vert\le \Vert Tx\Vert \le A \Vert x\Vert$$
Now consider the operator  $S = r T$ where $r >0$ we shall choose.
We will have 
$$ a r \Vert x\Vert \le \Vert S x\Vert\le  A r \Vert x\Vert$$
We want  $A r = 1+\varepsilon$. So choose $r= \frac{1+\varepsilon}{A}$.
Now we have $\Vert S x\Vert \le (1+\varepsilon)\Vert x\Vert$.
Finally we want also that $ar >1-\varepsilon$, or that
$a\frac{1+\varepsilon}{A}>1-\varepsilon$.
It is clear that we may choose $\varepsilon<1$ sufficiently close to $1$ so 
that this is true also.

Comment: Yes, and the question as posed, has nothing to do with $l_p$. It is just rescaling an isomorphism $T$ such that $||T||$ is small, and consequently $||T^{-1}||$ is large. I suspect that he meant $1/(1+\epsilon)$ instead of $1-\epsilon, in which case *I think* it is not true if $S$ is required to be an isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$, but it is true for all $\epsilon>0$ if is not.    

Comment: I will not call this almost isometric because ε is not small. 

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no when $p\not= 2$.  For any fixed $M$ you can take a finite dimensional subspace $E$ of $\ell_p$ such that the factorization constant through $\ell_p$  of the identity on $E$ is larger than $M$.  Then $E\oplus_p \ell_p$ is isometrically a subspace of $\ell_p$ that is isomorphic to $\ell_p$ but the isomorphism constant is larger than $M$.